# React: Drag div with minimal footprint and with model / view separation

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, reactjs, draggable

What is the best way to make a react-rendered DOM element draggable

- without using external stuff like jQuery
- with minimal code-footprint
- with correct separation of view- and model-scope

So far this is the principal of my code (ES6, transpiled by babel.js in webpack):

**View**

```
export default React.createClass({

    isDragged(){
        console.log('what now?')  
    },

    render () {
        return(
            <div draggable='true' onDrag={this.isDragged}>
            </div>
        )
    }
})
```

**Model**

```
export default Model.extend({
    props: {
        x: 'number',
        y: 'number'
    }
})
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20926551/recommended-way-of-making-react-component-div-draggable

Answer (score 0):

There is a great library called react-dnd that can help

http://gaearon.github.io/react-dnd/