# Integrating jQuery plugin with React

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I'm using **jQuery nestable plugin** https://dbushell.com/Nestable/ in my React App. I know that there will be problems when we use jQuery in React.

jQuery nestable solves my business needs, can't find the exact requirements in react drag/nestable components. So I have used this jQuery plugin.

The real problem is :  while dragging an element by using this jQuery plugin, it clones the DOM, apart from this everything is in react.

Initialized the jQuery nestable functionality like below:

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.$node = $(this.nestable); // this.nestable is a ref

    this.$node.nestable({
        group: 1,
        maxDepth: 4,
        expandBtnHTML:"",
        collapseBtnHTML:""
    });
}
```

the above code will let me drag the group2 among all other DOM elements like below image:

[image]

group2 is the draggable element here.

after dragged, I can see that group2 apperaed twice and I guess jQuery plugin clones the dragged element like below:

[image]

and in developer tools :
[image]

But In react developer tools, I can see that DOM is correct.
[image]

I don't know, how to rectify this problem. I'm unable to update the full code here because the code base is large.

In react developer tools, I can see that DOM is correct, and in native DOM is not !!

Is it possible to replace native DOM by virtual DOM after setState or is it possible for react to trace DOM handled by jQuery ?

I accept @ Patrick Evans comments, I'm looking for a solution here or suitable react based component like jQuery nestable.

Any help on this will be helpful.

Comment: more than likely it's the other way around. When jquery allows dragging of the element it takes it out of where it was, and during the next react cycle, react recreates the elements thus making it appear like it was cloned.

Comment: maybe take a look at [react-nestable](https://github.com/primetwig/react-nestable).

Comment: @PatrickEvans got the point but I really don't know how to rectify this. But I can see that cloned element appears in native dom developer tool

Comment: @TomaszMularczyk in react-nestable , the drag option will be Array of items. but in my case I want to customize the DOM and design, So I moved to  jQuery nestable plugin

Comment: Why you mix jQuery plugin with react? There are couple drag and drop plugins for react that you can use like http://react-dnd.github.io/react-dnd/ or https://github.com/atlassian/react-beautiful-dnd. Well with them you have to implement the logic yourself, but it's not that hard :)

Comment: You should take a look at https://frontend-collective.github.io/react-sortable-tree/

Comment: Don't mix JQuery with React.js for DOM changes, if you do that you will have a lot of performance issues. I think you should try @Petroff recommendations.

Comment: Check this : https://reactjs.org/docs/integrating-with-other-libraries.html

Comment: @Petroff Thanks and totally agree with you, we can't mix jQuery with react

Comment: @Petroff. In my case i'm implementing react in my existing app, so can't change the API , only change is UI, in react-nestable or react-dnd, I should apply the Array of items as their docs suggest, so i chose jquery. The API will be still same and I need to apply the drag and drop nestable in this.

Answer (score 1):

[React-nestable](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-nestable) seems to have the same behavior as that jQuery plugin and could save you a lot of trouble. Mixing jQuery with React is super easy to cause trouble in my experience.

Answer (score 0):

There is one hacky solution here:

In Nestable you have on change event. So you keep order of list as a state of component and while you drag and drop an element you can update the state and list should be re-rendered.

Please see that you can use key in list elements to optimize it a bit.

I am sure this will solve your issue.

Comment: Thanks. Yes i did the same way as your's , did setState while onchange, the problem is while dragging that drag node  will be placed in a native dom, and the re-render happens react will place the virtual dom to native dom. Because react doesn't know there's a dom placed in native which is react's out of control.

Comment: When onChange happens and you do setState, You should update whole container which contains them as native dom will also be placed in it and will be removed by it. Also i have mentioned in answer also to use keys in list elements.

Comment: will take a work around on this and let you know shortly @Hriday Modi