# React component dragging not working, no errors or console logs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I tried to modify this SO post [Recommended way of making React component/div draggable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20926551/recommended-way-of-making-react-component-div-draggable) to work with an es6 class but none of the event bindings are firing for some reason, Im not getting any errors though. None of my logs are printing anything.

```
// Dragging implementation https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20926551/recommended-way-of-making-react-component-div-draggable
export default class Clip extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      pos: this.props.initialPos,
      dragging: false,
      rel: null // position relative to the cursor
    };
  }

  /*  we could get away with not having this (and just having the listeners on
   our div), but then the experience would be possibly be janky. If there's
   anything w/ a higher z-index that gets in the way, then you're toast,
   etc.*/
  componentDidUpdate(props, state) {
    if (this.state.dragging && !state.dragging) {
      document.addEventListener('mousemove', this.onMouseMove);
      document.addEventListener('mouseup', this.onMouseUp);
    } else if (!this.state.dragging && state.dragging) {
      document.removeEventListener('mousemove', this.onMouseMove);
      document.removeEventListener('mouseup', this.onMouseUp);
    }
  }

  // calculate relative position to the mouse and set dragging=true
  onMouseDown(e) {
    console.log('onMouseDown', e);

    // only left mouse button
    if (e.button !== 0) return;
    var pos = $(this.getDOMNode()).offset();
    this.setState({
      dragging: true,
      rel: {
        x: e.pageX - pos.left,
        y: e.pageY - pos.top
      }
    });
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
  }

  onMouseUp(e) {
    console.log('onMouseUp', e);

    this.setState({ dragging: false });
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
  }

  onMouseMove(e) {
    if (!this.state.dragging) return;

    console.log('onMouseMove', e);

    this.setState({
      pos: {
        x: e.pageX - this.state.rel.x,
        y: e.pageY - this.state.rel.y
      }
    });
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="clip-component" style={ clipStyle(this.props) }>

      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was missing `onMouseDown={ this.onMouseDown }` attribute in the rendered div.