# How to implement a draggable React component

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I'm getting back into React and am wanting to have some components which can be dragged around by the user on the website I'm making. Note, by draggable I mean 'moved around the page by mouse', not the ['drag and drop'](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API) kind of draggable.

My code so far kind of works but is a bit jerky and does not always register when the mouse is up/released.

This is the component I'm trying to make draggable.

```
import React from 'react';

export default class Folder extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {mouseDown: false,
                    name: props.name, 
                    left: props.left,
                    top:props.top   
                 };
  } 

  // mouse down -> grab coords and offset
  // mouse move, if mouse down true, make mouse coords 
  // folder coords
  // on mouse up change mouse down to false.(can't move)

  mouseHandler(e){
    this.setState({mouseDown: true})
  }
  mouseMove(e){
    if(!this.state.mouseDown){
        return
    }else{
        console.log('mouse held and moving')
        let newLeft = e.clientX - e.nativeEvent.offsetX
        let newTop = e.clientY - e.nativeEvent.offsetY
        this.setState({left: newLeft, top:newTop})
    }
  }
  mouseUp(e){
    this.setState({mouseDown: false})
    console.log('mouse up')
  }



  render() {
    return  (<div className="icon" 
             onMouseDown={(e) => this.mouseHandler(e)}
             onMouseMove={(e) => this.mouseMove(e)}
             onMouseUp={(e) => this.mouseUp(e)}
             style={{top: this.state.top, left: this.state.left}} >
                <div className="tab"></div>
                <div className="foldergap"></div>
                <div className="foldertitle"><p>{this.state.name}</p>/div>
            </div>)
  }
};
```

I know there are libraries I could use but I would like to use my own work where I can. I have also seen this similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20926551/recommended-way-of-making-react-component-div-draggable) but the answers either seemed to use outdated techniques, DOM manipulation (which doesn't seem like the 'React way') or libraries.

My question is what am I doing wrong and what is the recommended way of achieving this functionality?

Thank you.

Comment: don't understand "drag around but not drag-n-drop", so what is drag around is for if you don't drop it somewhere?

Comment: Sure. I want something like this for react : https://jqueryui.com/draggable/
NOT like this : https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_draganddrop.asp
They are clearly different in the look and effect but I have seen them both referred to as 'draggable' and I just wanted it to be obvious:)