# React enable drag events on not draggable element

Tags: javascript, reactjs

a very simple question - but did not found a simple answer.
I want to enable drag events (onDragStart,onDrag,onDragEnd etc) on an element, but I don't want the element to animate drag when trying to drag (like when passing `draggable` to the component does).
how do I achieve this?

```
<div
  onDragStart={() => console.log("onDragStart")} //does not fire
  // draggable   // dont want this - or just disable animation when trying to drag
>
  someContent
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by animation? Avatar?

Comment: Just need the html [draggable](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_draggable.asp) attribute for certain elements

Comment: If an avatar, you can turn it off or even make your own. You cannot do without the draggable attribute. Or you have to write all the logic yourself.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20926551/recommended-way-of-making-react-component-div-draggable

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Recommended way of making React component/div draggable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20926551/recommended-way-of-making-react-component-div-draggable)

Comment: absolutely no @jmkmay , i'm interested in react EVENTS not to make it actually draggable.

Answer (score 2):

After trying a bit myself, I came to the answer.
pass `draggable` to enable drag events on the element, and to disable animation prevent default on onDragStart.

will leave the answer here if anyone will also need it.

```
<div
  onDragStart={(e) => {
              console.log("onDragStart") // do what you need here
              e.preventDefault();        // then prevent animation
            }}
  draggable   
>
  someContent
</div>
```

## EDIT

this is some advancement but not answers fully answer my question.
what I did is not canceling the animation, but actually canceling animation and all the drag events coming next on the same element. but I need this element to fire on `onDrop` event(I did not forget to e.preventDefault() on onDragOver).
i need the `onDrop` event to fire. so I can I truly disable animation but let the rest of the drag events fire regularly?

### Codesandbox

https://codesandbox.io/s/drag-with-not-animation-b3eh7?file=/src/App.js
come'on guys. you can do it. here's a sample

## got it

finally got it.
it is possible to disable animation by passing empty image to the draged element, by using [DataTransfer.setDragImage()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DataTransfer/setDragImage) function.

```
const emptyImg = new Image();
<div
  onDragStart={(e) => e.dataTransfer.setDragImage(emptyImg, 0, 0)}
  draggable   
>
  someContent
</div>
```

## EDIT: NO

I still need help here.
you can turn off the animation, but the behavior would still be as a draggable element.

I just need to turn on drag Event but without enable the draggable browser behavior for the element.

help!