# How to make a video draggable over the video in react js

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

Here i want  `localVideo` to be draggable over the `remoteVideo` (it should not draggable out of remote video) but `localVideo`  is not dragging. what is wrong here i don't understand

please help me thanks in advance

```
      <Draggable bounds="parent">   
          <video id="localVideo"  autoPlay playsInline controls={false}}/>       
      </Draggable>
      <div>
          <video id="remoteVideo" autoPlay playsInline controls={false} />  
      </div>
```

css:

```
 #localVideo{
    height:20%;
    width:55%;
    position:absolute
 }

#remoteVideo{
  width:"80%"; 
  height:"80%"
}
```

Comment: your question is not clear? you want localvedio should be locate over remotevedio?

Comment: using css i located the localvideo over the remote video, but i want  localVideo to be draggable over the remote video

Comment: check out this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20926551/recommended-way-of-making-react-component-div-draggable

Comment: is it possible to drag the video over the video?