# React Draggable div element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, draggable, drag, react-functional-component

Will be possible to build a draggable element using in React, following these conditions ?

1-Using React functional components

2-Not using 3rd libraries

3-To be similar to these example:
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_draggable.asp

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes, and you can get good info in this answer :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20926551/recommended-way-of-making-react-component-div-draggable